# A large place to plant some berries

Tags: pokemon-uranium

I'm looking for a large place where I can plant berries and from time to time return there and collect whatever is available.

Is there a location where I can do that in a large scale?

Something around 10 squares or more.

Answer (score 2):

Route 9 (or the route besides Legen Town) has around 10 squares.